# c# Tableadapter fails to update through odbc

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, odbc, tableadapter

I have a complicated issue to solve.
Basically i have a winform application which uses datasets and access files to save data.

Now i have a customer which would like to have the database stored on a sql server.

So .. i made the database in sql and an mdb file with odbc tables attached to it.

And here is the issue.. The program works only in reading and inserting new data. When the user tries to update an existing row the tableadapter goes in concurrency exception.

I can't really understand the reason or how to solve this.
Anybody got any idea or any tips about this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171936.aspx

Comment: i don't think it fits my issue.
The data is edited by just one  user at time. So the row get changes after the fill method

Comment: How do you know that it is concurrency issue? Show relevant code please.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/HGqcTJ8.jpg